# PHP & word counting from string

Tags: php, arrays, count

Trying to take numbers from a text file and see how many times they occur.
I've gotten to the point where I can print all of them out, but I want to display just the number once, and then maybe the occurrences after them (ie: Key | Amount; 317 | 42).
Not looking for an Answer per se, all learning is good, but if you figure one out for me, that would be awesome as well!

Comment: Show us what you've got so far, and we can offer better advice.

Comment: $numbers=file_get_contents('names.txt');
$convert = explode(" ", $numbers);
for ($i=0;$i<count($convert);$i++) 
{
    //sort values in array asc.
    echo $convert[$i]."<br />";
}
so far, it just lists the numbers to the screen for my convenience.

Answer (score 1):

preg_match_all will return the number of matches against a string.

```
$count = preg_match_all("#$key#", $string);
print "{$key} - {$count}";
```

Comment: In order to use `preg_match_all` here, you'd first have to get a list of all the unique words in the file.  While you're in the process of doing that you can easily count their occurrences. Running `preg_match_all` after you've gotten the list would just be wasteful.

Comment: @itchy Am I misreading the question? He says he's trying to match a string thats taken from a text file. Why would you count unique words?

Comment: "Trying to take numbers from a text file and see how many times they occur." Meaning there is a text file containing numbers, some of which are repeated, and he has to extract all of those numbers and count how many times they each occur. I can't think of any other meaning for that, though I could be misreading it too.

Comment: the numbers are random and unknown, so thats where it gets a little weird. i could understand using RegEx and such, but i don't know the numbers which i am working with.

Answer (score 1):

So if you're already extracting the data you need, you can do this using a (fairly) simple array:

```
$counts = array();

foreach ($keysFoundFromFile AS $key) {
    if (!$counts[$key]) $counts[$key] = 0;
    $counts[$key]++;
}

print_r($counts);
```

If you're already looping to extract the keys from the file, then you can simply assign them directly to the `$counts` array without making a second loop.

Answer (score 1):

I think you're looking for the function [substr_count()](http://us.php.net/substr_count).
Just a heads up though, if you're looking for "123" and it finds "4512367" it will match it as part of it.  The alternative would be using RegEx and using word boundaries:

`$count = preg_match_all('|\b'. preg_quote($num) .'\b|', $text);`

(`preg_quote()` for good practice, `\b` for word boundaries so we can be assured that it's not a number embedded in another number.)